# How to determine a Multicast MAC Address with PHP5?

Tags: php, symfony1, multicast, mac-address

I'm working on a Accounting Tool in PHP which connects to a CISCO Switch and insert a MAC Address on a specified port. I use Symfony as my underlying php framework.

If I try to insert a Multicast MAC address as a FastEthernet secure address the CISCO Switch reject the address. So I try to build a validator which determine if the given MAC address is a multicast address or not.

Is there someone out there who can help me with a snippet or tip?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
function isPhysicalAddress($address){
    if (strlen($address) > 17) return 0;

    if ($address == "") return 0;

    if (!eregi("^[0-9A-Z]+(\-[0-9A-Z]+)+(\-[0-9A-Z]+)+(\-[0-9A-Z]+)+(\-[0-9A-Z]+)+(\-[0-9A-Z]+)$", $address)) return 0;

    $arr=explode("-",$address);

    if (strlen($arr[0]) != 2) return 0;
    if (strlen($arr[1]) != 2) return 0;
    if (strlen($arr[2]) != 2) return 0;
    if (strlen($arr[3]) != 2) return 0;
    if (strlen($arr[4]) != 2) return 0;
    if (strlen($arr[5]) != 2) return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Found [here](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-3183.html).

Comment: Sorry darmen, but this is not an answer to my question. I know how to validate a mac-address but I don't know to find out if this address is a "multicast" mac-address. This is much more complicate as just have a simple regex call.